# How to add Azure SignalR to health checks

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, health-check, azure-signalr

I try to add Azure SignalR healt check using nuget package `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SignalR`. I use this code

```
 services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSignalRHub(
       Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSignalR"),
       name: "Azure SignalR");
```

but when I run app in healtcheck window I got info

```
Unhealthy
Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
```

My URI scheme: `Endpoint=https://xxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=******;Version=1.0;`

How should be look like this URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is non-existent but if you take a look at the tests they have written you can see that its expected to be an http endpoint of the Azure SignalR rather than a connection string:

https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/test/HealthChecks.SignalR.Tests/Functional/SignalRHealthCheckTests.cs

And under the hood its basically :

```
    Func<HubConnection> hubConnectionBuilder = () =>
        new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(url)
            .Build();
```

as you can see here https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/src/HealthChecks.SignalR/DependencyInjection/SignalRHealthCheckBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: But if you only specify the url, how can you specify the AccesKey?

Comment: You don't, its just a health check not an authorization